# just bought universal power supply, how adapt it to my laptop

Tags: laptop, battery, power, charger

i just bought an universal power charger but does not adapt to the right voltage. The original charger is 19.5 v and 6.15 a, and the charger i bought is 12/15/16/18/19/20/24 v and 4.5 a. What should i do?

Answer (score 3):

Buy a different charger.

The charger you bought only has current of 4.5a, apparently you need 6.15a or somewhere closer to that.   FWIW, the charger you buy could be anything over 6.15a, just not under.   The voltage should match exactly, although 19 might work.

That UNIVERSAL unit isn't so universal.